# Sending an object into another object, like it belongs there C++

Tags: c++, class, object

I need to send one object/struct into another object/struct and make it be a member of the second object/struct, so that I don't need to send it as argument to every method in the second object/struct... I use the "STRUCT NAME& newname", but it only works for that specific method. How can I make it public/accessible to the whole scope of that struct/object?

```
    '''

        struct MEM
        {
            unsigned char RAM[8192];
            // some code, etc.
        };


        struct CPU
        {
            // some declarations 
            
            void init(MEM& memory)
            {
                // now 'memory' points to that MEM struct
                //some code 
                // 
            }
        };


        int main()
        {
            CPU cpu;
            MEM mem;

            cpu.init(mem);

            return 0;
        }


    '''
```

in the above example, I need memory to be treated as a normal member of CPU.

Comment: `struct CPU` should have a member variable `MEM* mem;` that it can use the passed via `init` MEM object, until such a point that it's replaced with a different MEM object (or reset to `nullptr`).  The CPU objects `mem` pointer is at the mercy of the caller for managing the lifespan of the MEM object that CPU is pointing to.

Comment: It's not possible to make one object go somewhere. Once an object is in a certain place, it stays in that place forever. Best you can do is make a new object, and transfer the data from the old object into the new one. Is that acceptable to you? (Or you can have a pointer pointing to the old object, like Eljay said)

Comment: Thanks, worked like a charm. I had to do without the * though!

Comment: @Torisoft notice the mem inside the CPU is not the same mem in the main function! if you do this, you have two mems

Comment: No, I need the secondary one to point to original one, so their contents stay the same at all times. In this example I might later add a video chip (for instance) that will definitely need to access the memory contents as well. This is quite easy in python, but I have not done C++ for years.

Comment: You're right user253751, they hold different values. I did what Eljay said, but had to drop the * because otherwise it raised an error:

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a `member variable` to your struct.

You can have 2 approaches here. A pointer approach or a copy approach.

Here is the pointer approach. This approach is lightweight, since it just keeps a pointer to a MEM struct.

```cpp
struct MEM
{
    unsigned char RAM[8192];
};


struct CPU
{
    void init(MEM* pMemory)
    {
        m_pMem = pMemory;
    }

    MEM* m_pMem;
};


int main()
{
    CPU cpu;
    MEM mem;

    cpu.init(&mem);
}
```

However, the problem with the pointer approach is that potentially you could point to invalid memory in the future. Here is an easy example:

```cpp
int main()
{
    CPU cpu;

    {
        MEM mem;
        cpu.init(&mem);
    } // mem goes out of scope

    // Now cpu.m_pMem is invalid since mem went out of scope.
}
```

So the other approach is to make a deep copy of the data.

```
struct MEM
{
    unsigned char RAM[8192];
};


struct CPU
{
    void init(MEM const& memory)
    {
        m_mem = memory;
    }

    MEM m_mem;
};


int main()
{
    CPU cpu = {};
    MEM mem = {};

    cpu.init(mem);
}
```

Now cpu has a copy of mem. And won't risk pointing to invalid data. However `mem` is not equal to `cpu.m_mem` since they are different pieces of data.

You need to pick the best approach for your circumstances.

Comment: Thank you very much. Seems like I have to stick to sending the object as argument for now.